# JSONStrore / WORKLIGHT

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

One little problem which JSONStore.add(data).then().fail()

The function `initialiserBD()` runs and returns success.  The function `remplireBD()` doesn't return success.  Surely, it is the function WL.JSONStore.get().add().then().fail()

> Object "errorObject" send error :-50 PERSISTENT_STORE_NOT_OPEN

```js
function wlCommonInit() {
   initialiserBD();
   remplireBD();
}

function initialiserBD() {
    var collectionName="Personnes" ;
    var collections = {};

    collections[collectionName]= {};
    collections[collectionName].searchFields={nom :'string'};

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function(){})
        .fail(function(errorObject) {
            alert(errorObject.tostring());
        });
}

function remplireBD(){
    var data = {
        nom :'Bill Gates'
    };
    var collectionName = 'Personnes';

    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data).then(function () {})
        .fail(function (errorObject) {
            alert(errorObject.toString());
        });
}
```

Comment: no problem witch the function initialiserBD().But  i have a problem witch the function remplireBD() and  i think the error is in this part
 " WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data).then(function () {})
         .fail(function (errorObject) { alert(errorObject.toString());});"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is two-fold...

1. You initialize the collection both before init and "after" init (`var collectionName="Personnes" ;`)
2. JavaScript is async, and you're calling `initialiserBD` and `remplireBD` one after the other instead of calling `remplireBD` in the success callback of `initialiserBD`, which could lead to trying to `.get()` before `init()` completed...